# How to access the thumbnails of the documents in a document list?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, web-services

I know the thumbnails exist, as when I use search, thumbnails appear next to my documents...

But, when I use the "**_vti_bin/Lists.asmx**" webservice to access my list, the thumbnail is not one of the fields I have access to... How can I access the thumbnails, via webservice?

Answer (score 1):

The thumbnails are only available with FAST search.

They are not a SharePoint list OOTB feature.

Perhaps you could use the `_vti_bin/search.asmx` service, but I don't think you can retrieve the thumbnails.

Comment: The "_vti_bin/search.asmx" webservice uses FAST to search?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394628.aspx#int_overview_web_service It uses whatever search you have set up. So yes, if your farm uses FAST. Otherwise, no.

Comment: **_vti_bin/search.asmx has no FAST preview thumbnail.** :( Had a look to the retrievable fields and that's not one of them...

Comment: I don't think they are accessible via web services.